# get Index of last Element in list without using lastIndexOf() or any other Java/String- Methods

Tags: java, list, loops, methods, char

I have an array

```
char [] data;
```

that is filled with different elements.
Looks like this:

```
 MyString str = new MyString(new char[]{'d','b','c','d'});
```

I have to write a method 
     public int lastIndex(char a)

that return the index of the last element. 
in the example from above: 3.

Im not allowed to use any Java methods. (for example String methods like charAt and so on)

I dont know where to start so this is all I got:

```
    public int lastIndex(char a)
    {

    int index = -1; 

    for (int i = 0; i<data.length;)
    {

    }

    return index; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the index of the last element, or the index of the last occurence of `char a`, because the former is literally `data.length - 1`.

Comment: @gurioso then you should have stated that in the question.

Comment: what to say? you can access array elements by index (`data[0]`), you can compare two chars by `==`, there are `if` statements in java.

Comment: You asked a similar question about an hour ago and when I helped you get the answer you deleted the question.

Comment: nasty, nasty ...

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. I have rolled it back so that it does not invalidate the answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works in getting the last index of a certain character:

```java
public int lastIndex(char a, char[] data) {
    int max=-1;
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
       if(data[i]==a) {
          max=i;
       }
    }
    return max;
}
```

It works by going through the array and finding the latest occurrence of a certain character. The variable 'max' is then set to this index. Once it goes through the whole array it will return 'max' if no character is found in the array it will just return '-1' since that's what 'max' was originally set to.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812) *It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment. You can use pseudo-code first, and, in the spirit of creating a programming resource, you may come back after a suitable amount of time and edit your response to include more complete code. This way, the student still has to write their code, but a full solution can become available after the assignment has ended.*

Comment: Thanks for the advice @KnowNoTrend I'll fix it ASAP

Comment: The question just disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the last index of the array then this will do

```
public int lastIndex() {
    return data.length - 1;
}
```

if you want to find specific character then please check @MorganS42 solution